# Energy Conservation in Quantum System?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Let us assume, 2 same mass atoms are moving towards each other at equal velocity and they are in course to crash into each other - so what would happen when they do crash into each other?

If we use the everyday physics intuition, it would tell us that both atoms will simply collide and will stop any sort of motion as the both momentum cancel each other out and so remain stationary. It sounds perfect as everything is good.  On other hand, my intuition says something different.

Looking at Heisenberg Uncertainty inequality:

$$\Delta{x}\Delta{\vec{p}} \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$

If we know $\Delta{\vec{p}}$ to complete accuracy (0) it will be impossible to make this inequality successful, as a result we cannot know $\Delta{\vec{p}}$ it must be some non-zero number so none of the particles will stop moving though their partner had enough momentum to stop the particles they will keep moving which is clear violation of conservation of momentum and so what will be needed to conserve this quantity?

So does this mean that LHC and other particle accelerators often break laws of conservation by doing this process?

Comment: Both particles will **not** simply collide and stop any sort of motion.

Comment: Hi I tried reading your question on 4 different browsers and on a separate tablet but the maths symbols do not render properly. Is it just me or could it need an edit?

Comment: I think it is just you, @irishphysics, because when I see it through chrome the math symbols appear properly.

Comment: Youre welcome, @irishphysics

Comment: @irishphysics: it's doing it to me as well. It's a bug in the SE somewhere that has been cropping up occasionally for the last week or so. It will eventually fix itself.

Comment: @irishphysics: see for example [this thread in the Physics chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=20611073#20611073)

Answer (score 2):

Your everyday physics intuition is leading you astray.

The kinetic energy of the incoming particles can't just disappear, so they can't just come to a stop unless they can transfer the kinetic energy into some other degree of freedom. If you collide two balls of clay they will come to a stop, but only because the kinetic energy can go into deforming and heating the clay. If you collide two electrons there aren't any degrees of freedom to absorb the energy. The kinetic energy after the collision will be the same as the kinetic energy before the collision, so the electrons can't just stop.

If the collision is energetic enough some of the energy can go into creating new particles, which is how the LHC makes Higgs bosons. But this destroys the original particles and creates a spray of new ones, so this can't reasonably be interpreted as coming to a stop. Any uncertainty in the momentum of the original protons results in an uncertainty in the momenta of the collision products. The LHC doesn't violate conservation of energy every time it collides two protons.

Comment: thanks John, just off the top of your head do you know of any page that deals with _thinking quantum mechanically instead of classically_.  I searched help with those terms.....but nada..........i was going to post it on physics meta, it's my particular failing learning Q.M. and maybe an explanatory page would help reduce above type questions, which I would ask as a question, no rush to answer, i can keep searching thanks

Comment: @irishphysics: it isn't useful to approach QM by starting with classical intuition and trying to mangle it into a QM form. You have to drop everything you thought you knew and just do the maths. Eventually you will build a new understanding. It takes time though - I've been working on it for the better part of forty years :-)

Comment: **mangle** is understating it in my case :)....BTW all maths rendering ok now....thanks, ok back to the study books for an hour now  regards,